# Complex custom Collector with Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have a stream of objects which I would like to collect the following way.

Let's say we are handling forum *posts*:

```
class Post {
    private Date time;
    private Data data
}
```

I want to create a list which groups *posts* by a period. If there were no *posts* for `X` minutes, create a *new group*.

```
class PostsGroup{
    List<Post> posts = new ArrayList<> ();
}
```

I want to get a `List<PostGroups>` containing the *posts* grouped by the interval.

*Example:* interval of `10` minutes.

*Posts:*

```
[{time:x, data:{}}, {time:x + 3, data:{}} , {time:x + 12, data:{}, {time:x + 45, data:{}}}]
```

I want to get a list of *posts group*:

```
[
 {posts : [{time:x, data:{}}, {time:x + 3, data:{}}, {time:x + 12, data:{}]]},
{posts : [{time:x + 45, data:{}]}
]
```

- notice that the first *group* lasted till `X + 22`. Then a *new post* was received at `X + 45`.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can convert the Date time into long by calling Day.getTime() which returns long telling current time in milliseconds. You can also convert 10 minutes into milliseconds which should be 10*60*1000. Now put some comparison logic on Day.getTime() to find next 10 minute entries.

Answer (score 3):

This problem could be easily solved using the [`groupRuns`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#groupRuns-java.util.function.BiPredicate-) method of my [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library:

```
long MAX_INTERVAL = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(10);
StreamEx.of(posts)
        .groupRuns((p1, p2) -> p2.time.getTime() - p1.time.getTime() <= MAX_INTERVAL)
        .map(PostsGroup::new)
        .toList();
```

I assume that you have a constructor

```
class PostsGroup {
    private List<Post> posts;

    public PostsGroup(List<Post> posts) {
        this.posts = posts;
    }
}
```

The `StreamEx.groupRuns` method takes a `BiPredicate` which is applied to two adjacent input elements and returns true if they must be grouped together. This method creates the stream of lists where each list represents the group. This method is lazy and works fine with parallel streams.

Answer (score 0):

You need to retain state between stream entries and write yourself a grouping classifier. Something like this would be a good start.

```
class Post {

    private final long time;
    private final String data;

    public Post(long time, String data) {
        this.time = time;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Post{" + "time=" + time + ", data=" + data + '}';
    }

}

public void test() {
    System.out.println("Hello");
    long t = 0;
    List<Post> posts = Arrays.asList(
            new Post(t, "One"),
            new Post(t + 1000, "Two"),
            new Post(t + 10000, "Three")
    );
    // Group every 5 seconds.
    Map<Long, List<Post>> gouped = posts
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(new ClassifyByTimeBetween(5000)));
    gouped.entrySet().stream().forEach((e) -> {
        System.out.println(e.getKey() + " -> " + e.getValue());
    });

}

class ClassifyByTimeBetween implements Function<Post, Long> {

    final long delay;
    long currentGroupBy = -1;
    long lastDateSeen = -1;

    public ClassifyByTimeBetween(long delay) {
        this.delay = delay;
    }

    @Override
    public Long apply(Post p) {
        if (lastDateSeen >= 0) {
            if (p.time > lastDateSeen + delay) {
                // Grab this one.
                currentGroupBy = p.time;
            }
        } else {
            // First time - start there.
            currentGroupBy = p.time;
        }
        lastDateSeen = p.time;
        return currentGroupBy;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since no one has provided a solution with a *custom collector* as it was required in the original problem statement, here is a *collector-implementation* that groups `Post` objects based on the provided time-interval.

`Date` class mentioned in the question is obsolete since Java 8 and not recommended to be used in new projects. Hence, `LocalDateTime` will be utilized instead.

#### Post & PostGroup

For testing purposes, I've used `Post` implemented as a Java 16 *record* (*if you substitute it with a class, the overall solution will be fully compliant with Java 8*):

```
public record Post(LocalDateTime dateTime) {}
```

Also, I've enhanced the `PostGroup` object. My idea is that it should be capable to decide whether the offered `Post` should be added to the *list of posts* or rejected as the [*Information expert principle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_(object-oriented_design)#Information_expert) suggests (*in short: all manipulations with the data should happen only inside a class to which that data belongs*).

To facilitate this functionality, two extra fields were added: `interval` of type [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/time/Duration.html) from the `java.time` package to represent the maximum *interval* between the *earliest post* and the *latest post* in a *group*, and `intervalBound` of type `LocalDateTime` which gets initialized after the first *post* will be added a later on will be used internally by the method `isWithinInterval()` to check whether the offered *post* fits into the *interval*.

```
public class PostsGroup {
    private Duration interval;
    private LocalDateTime intervalBound;
    private List<Post> posts = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public PostsGroup(Duration interval) {
        this.interval = interval;
    }
    
    public boolean tryAdd(Post post) {
        if (posts.isEmpty()) {
            intervalBound = post.dateTime().plus(interval);
            return posts.add(post);
        } else if (isWithinInterval(post)) {
            return posts.add(post);
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    public boolean isWithinInterval(Post post) {
        return post.dateTime().isBefore(intervalBound);
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PostsGroup{" + posts + '}';
    }
}
```

I'm making two assumptions:

- All posts in the source are sorted by time (if it is not the case, you should introduce `sorted()` operation in the pipeline before collecting the results);
- Posts need to be collected into the minimum number of groups, as a consequence of this it's not possible to split this task and execute stream in parallel.

#### Building a Custom Collector

We can create a *custom collector* either inline by using one of the versions of the static method [`Collector.of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BinaryOperator,java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...)) or by defining a `class` that implements the `Collector` interface.

These *parameters* have to be provided while creating a *custom collector*:

- **Supplier** `Supplier<A>` is meant to provide a *mutable container* which store elements of the stream. In this case, `ArrayDeque` (as an implementation of the `Deque` interface) will be handy as a *container* to facilitate the convenient access to the most recently added element, i.e. the latest `PostGroup`.
- **Accumulator** `BiConsumer<A,T>` defines how to add elements into the *container* provided by the *supplier*. For this task, we need to provide the logic on that will allow determining whether the next element from the stream (i.e. the next `Post`) should go into the last `PostGroup` in the `Deque`, or a new `PostGroup` needs to be allocated for it.
- **Combiner** `BinaryOperator<A> combiner()` establishes a rule on how to merge two *containers* obtained while executing stream in parallel. Since this operation is treated as not parallelizable, the *combiner* is implemented to throw an `AssertionError` in case of parallel execution.
- **Finisher** `Function<A,R>` is meant to produce the final result by transforming the mutable container. The *finisher* function in the code below turns the *container*, a *deque* containing the result, into an *immutable list*.

***Note:*** Java 16 method `toList()` is used inside the *finisher* function, for Java 8 it can be replaced with `collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableList())` or `collect(Collectors.toList())`.

- **Characteristics** allow providing additional information, for instance `Collector.Characteristics.UNORDERED` which is used in this case denotes that the order in which partial results of the reduction produced while executing in parallel is not significant. In this case, *collector* doesn't require any characteristics.

The method below is responsible for generating the *collector* based on the provided *interval*.

```
public static Collector<Post, ?, List<PostsGroup>> groupPostsByInterval(Duration interval) {
    
    return Collector.of(
        ArrayDeque::new,
        (Deque<PostsGroup> deque, Post post) -> {
            if (deque.isEmpty() || !deque.getLast().tryAdd(post)) { // if no groups have been created yet or if adding the post into the most recent group fails
                PostsGroup postsGroup = new PostsGroup(interval);
                postsGroup.tryAdd(post);
                deque.addLast(postsGroup);
            }
        },
        (Deque<PostsGroup> left, Deque<PostsGroup> right) -> { throw new AssertionError("should not be used in parallel"); },
        (Deque<PostsGroup> deque) -> deque.stream().collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toUnmodifiableList())));
}
```

`main()` - demo

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Post> posts =
        List.of(new Post(LocalDateTime.of(2022,4,28,15,0)),
                new Post(LocalDateTime.of(2022,4,28,15,3)),
                new Post(LocalDateTime.of(2022,4,28,15,5)),
                new Post(LocalDateTime.of(2022,4,28,15,8)),
                new Post(LocalDateTime.of(2022,4,28,15,12)),
                new Post(LocalDateTime.of(2022,4,28,15,15)),
                new Post(LocalDateTime.of(2022,4,28,15,18)),
                new Post(LocalDateTime.of(2022,4,28,15,27)),
                new Post(LocalDateTime.of(2022,4,28,15,48)),
                new Post(LocalDateTime.of(2022,4,28,15,54)));
    
    Duration interval = Duration.ofMinutes(10);

    List<PostsGroup> postsGroups = posts.stream()
        .collect(groupPostsByInterval(interval));
    
    postsGroups.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

*Output:*

```
PostsGroup{[Post[dateTime=2022-04-28T15:00], Post[dateTime=2022-04-28T15:03], Post[dateTime=2022-04-28T15:05], Post[dateTime=2022-04-28T15:08]]}
PostsGroup{[Post[dateTime=2022-04-28T15:12], Post[dateTime=2022-04-28T15:15], Post[dateTime=2022-04-28T15:18]]}
PostsGroup{[Post[dateTime=2022-04-28T15:27]]}
PostsGroup{[Post[dateTime=2022-04-28T15:48], Post[dateTime=2022-04-28T15:54]]}
```

*You can also play around with* [*this Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/rgd)