# Grouping Java 8 Dates in intervals

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, java-time

Using Java 8 java.time framework, how can Dates be grouped into intervals?
For example, every 10 minutes as an interval, and a list of given [`LocalTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html)

`List<LocalTime> list = Arrays.asList(LocalTime.of(0,9),LocalTime.of(0,11),LocalTime.of(0,19));`

If grouping with an interval of 10 minutes, `LocalTime.of(0,9)` should be in the first group, but `LocalTime.of(0,11),LocalTime.of(0,19)` in the second interval.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using the Java 8 time API, this can be done quite convienently:

```
Map<Integer, List<LocalTime>> map = 
     list.stream()
          .collect(Collectors.
                 groupingBy(x -> x.get(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_DAY) / 10)
                  );
```

This example would use a [`LocalTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) and group your posts in groups of 10 minutes.

<sup>Note: This was originally an answer to [Java 8 complex custom collector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34417261/java-8-complex-custom-collector) , but since it did not address OPs question, and got some upvotes, I deleted it and wrote a question for it. Changed order of calls according to JodaStephen's comment</sup>

Comment: Preferred way round is `x.getTime().get(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_DAY)`, because it reads more nicely and works with third party `TemporalAccessor` implementations slightly better.

Comment: What would you have to do if you wanted to use the original localtime but still sort on subset of it ? So that your map looks like <LocalTime, List<LocalTime> ?

Comment: @axl: I am not sure what your input/output is, but maybe you could ask a new question with a more detailed description of your problem.

Comment: @user140547 Like say if you wanted to sort on a subset of local(date)time (for instance months, days, hours, minutes, seconds) but since your get returns Integer, you have to map Integer. My question is about how to keep a local(date)time but with the right grouping. So if you would have a list of times and you wanted to group on hour instead of having ints going from 0-23 have localtimes going 0-23 ... I guess you would have to make an extra get method for that object returning the localtime with that info?

Comment: this is a perfect answer but what if I have LocalDateTime and I want to group by minutes